# MVC Switch from Code First to Database first - alter schema without dropping database

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first, ef-database-first

With Entity Framework it is possible to enable migrations and create migration steps. But is there an intermediate way where it is possible to change the models, and take care of database schema changes yourself? I don't want to drop the database, because there are future production schenario's.

Now - without enable migrations - I use a code first, and when I create another property in a DbSet - lets assume for example in table 'ExistingTable' int NewField {get; set;}
And when in SQL I update my schema with
Alter table ExistingTable add column NewField int not null

the database knows existence of the new field, the Entity Framework / C# knows the property, but when running, there is some hidden check that still want's to drop my database because of the model change.
Question: can I overwrite a certain setting, in such a way that intial 'Code First' can be transformed to database first?

Comment: This is not the answer, but you can try database first. Remove your model, add new item data/ADO.NET Entity Database Model

Answer (score 0):

Removing the __MigrationHistory table from the database (Azure) did work fine for me. I made my (simple) database changes myself and published the code. It all runs fine. There is an alternative see [EF Code First Migrations Deployment to an Azure Cloud Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx). For a simple one-way patch (and no change history needed) removing the __MigrationHistory works fine.